# Force window.navigator.pointerEnabled to false

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How can I force `window.navigator.pointerEnabled` to false on IE?

```
 window.navigator.pointerEnabled = false;
```

Doesn't work.

I can't touch that code but would like to be in the else case in anycase:

```
if (window.navigator.pointerEnabled) {
      tapEventListener('pointerdown');
      tapEventListener('pointerup');
      tapEventListener('pointcancel');
      tapTouchMoveListener = 'pointermove';
} else if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
      tapEventListener('MSPointerDown');
      tapEventListener('MSPointerUp');
      tapEventListener('MSPointerCancel');
      tapTouchMoveListener = 'MSPointerMove';
} else {
      tapEventListener('touchstart');
      tapEventListener('touchend');
      tapEventListener('touchcancel');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it:

```js
Object.defineProperty(navigator.__proto__, 'pointerEnabled', { value: false });

console.log(window.navigator.pointerEnabled);
```

The reason why `navigator.pointerEnabled = false` doesn't work is that the property is read-only. You can see it if you enter in the console:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(navigator.__proto__, 'pointerEnabled')
```

And note that the `set` member is `undefined`.